# Bash Script : Edit .txt by Line

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, scripting

I have a text file with unknown length. There are two values on each line:

```
VALUE1[SPACE]VALUE2
```

Now I have to get another (or the same) file with a new List like:

```
0.0.0.0/rep/com/bla/blub/VALUE1/VALUE2/VALUE1-VALUE2.zip
```

...for each line I have in the list with the two values. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good usecase for awk (Updated to take care of the parantheses):

```
awk -F" " '{ gsub("\\(", "", $1); gsub("\\)", "", $2);print "0.0.0.0/rep/com/bla/blub/"$1"/"$2"/"$1"-"$2".zip"}' test.txt > yournewfile.txt
```

This will split each line with a space, replace the opening parentheses in your first token `$1` and replace the closing parentheses in your second toke `$2` and then use values in their respective tokens `$1` and `$2` in the string you are outputing with `print`

Comment: this only works for first value set or not ?  i need to edit line by line to get for each line a link with the values from this line :/

Comment: This will go through every line in your input file and create a new line in your output file.

Comment: Please undelete [your recent SQL answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28683389/57611). It could still be helpful to others besides the OP (just be clear that it only works in SQL Server 2012 and up).

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `VALUE1` and `VALUE2` contain no spaces, otherwise the first definition becomes ambigous. With this hypothesis, you can split a line at the first space using `cut` and compose the `filename` variable using string interpolation:

```
cat txt-File | while read VALUE1 VALUE2 _; do
    filename="0.0.0.0/rep/com/bla/blub/$VALUE1/$VALUE2/$VALUE1-$VALUE2.zip"

    # Do something with filename...
    stat "$filename"
done
```

Comment: `while read VALUE1 VALUE2 _; do ... done <file` would avoid pesky external processes and be somewhat more idiomatic.

Comment: uff, you can simplify this very much: `cat file | while` is not necessary, you can say `while ... done < file`. Also, `read` can read more than one argument by saying `while read value1 value2 ...`

Comment: I prefer the leading `cat file` because it makes obvious what the loop is processing, without having to scroll to the bottom. Fixed the other thing.

Comment: This can be an interesting read: [I set variables in a loop that's in a pipeline. Why do they disappear after the loop terminates? Or, why can't I pipe data to read?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024)

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo: a shame you can't put the `<file` at the front of the loop like you can with a regular single command.  It would be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

The format of your input data file is `(VALUE1 VALUE2).`. You first remove the initial `(`, and latter `).` There are many ways to do this, here is one

```
sed 's/(//g' yourfile | sed 's/).//g'
```

You can then pass this over to `awk`. Here `$1` corresponds to the first column, and `$2` to the second:

```
sed 's/(//g' yourfile | sed 's/).//g' | awk '{print "0.0.0.0/rep/com/bla/blub/"$1"/"$2"/"$1"-"$2".zip"}'
```

Comment: I suggest you just try it out for yourself ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I would use `sed` for this:

```
sed $'s,^[ \t]*\([^ \t]*\)[ \t][ \t]*\([^ \t]*\).*$,0.0.0.0/rep/com/bla/blub/\1/\2/\1-\2.zip,' filename >new-filename
```

You could modify the original file in place if you prefer by adding `-i.bak`: `sed -i.bak $'s,`...`,'`.