# SQL Get Last Occurrence of Field Against Each Row

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How can I add the LastDocumentID column like so:

```
+------------+-----------+----------------+
| DocumentID | Reference | LastDocumentID |
+------------+-----------+----------------+
|          1 | A         | NULL           |
|          2 | A         | 1              |
|          3 | A         | 2              |
|          4 | B         | NULL           |
|          5 | B         | 4              |
|          6 | C         | NULL           |
|          7 | C         | 6              |
|          8 | C         | 7              |
|          9 | C         | 8              |
+------------+-----------+----------------+
```

The table could be in a random order, but in the Last Document ID I essentially want it to get the Max Document ID that is less than that row's Document ID for that row's Reference.

Comment: And what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get any value from the "last document" this way:

```
SELECT
   D.DocumentID,
   D.Reference,
   LastDocumentID = R.DocumentID
FROM
   dbo.Documents D
   OUTER APPLY (
      SELECT TOP 1 *
      FROM dbo.Documents R
      WHERE
         D.Reference = R.Reference
         AND R.DocumentID < D.DocumentID
      ORDER BY R.DocumentID DESC
   ) R
;
```

## [See this working in a SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9fc74/2)

Though having identical logic to similar methods that compute just the column value in a subquery in the `WHERE` clause, this allows you to pull multiple columns from the previous document, and demonstrates `OUTER APPLY`. Change to `CROSS APPLY` if you want the equivalent `INNER` join (excluding rows that have no previous).

For reference, here's the single-value way to do it. You basically put the query contained in the `OUTER APPLY` into parentheses, and only select one column:

```
SELECT
   D.DocumentID,
   D.Reference,
   LastDocumentID = (
      SELECT TOP 1 R.DocumentID
      FROM dbo.Documents R
      WHERE
         D.Reference = R.Reference
         AND R.DocumentID < D.DocumentID
      ORDER BY R.DocumentID DESC
   )
FROM
   dbo.Documents D
;
```

Alternately, you can just use `Max`:

```
SELECT
   D.DocumentID,
   D.Reference,
   LastDocumentID = (
      SELECT Max(R.DocumentID)
      FROM dbo.Documents R
      WHERE
         D.Reference = R.Reference
         AND R.DocumentID < D.DocumentID
   )
FROM
   dbo.Documents D
;
```

If you were using SQL Server 2012 and up, you could do it this way using its more advanced syntax available for windowing functions:

```
SELECT
    D.DocumentID,
    D.Reference,
    LastDocumentID = Max(D.DocumentID) OVER (
       PARTITION BY D.Reference
       ORDER BY D.DocumentID ASC
       ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
    )
FROM
    dbo.Documents D
;
```

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server 2012+ you can use `lag()`.  In SQL Server 2008, you can use a correlated subquery or outer apply.  Here is one method:

```
select documentid, reference,
       (select top 1 documentid
        from table t2
        where t2.reference = t.reference and
              t2.documentid < t.documentid
        order by documentid desc
       ) as LastDocumentId
from table t;
```

Comment: You aren't sorting inside the subquery.

Comment: I think this could also be done using `MAX(documentid)` instead of `top 1 documentid` and leaving out the `order by` clause.

Answer (score 0):

I was asked to undelete this with the following caveat... for SQL Server versions greater than 2008:

You could accomplish this with Window functions

```
SELECT
    DocumentID,
    Reference,
    MAX(DocumentID) OVER (PARTITION BY Reference ORDER BY DocumentID ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS LastDocumentID
FROM
    <table>
```

That longer line is the window function will fetch the max(documentid) from the group of rows that are partitioned by your reference field and are limited by all the previous documentids for that reference not including the current document.

Comment: SQL Server 2008 does support windowing functions, but not the `ROWS` clause.

Answer (score 0):

`LAG` might be more efficient if that's an option. But there's no particular reason to use `TOP` when `MAX` works great.

```
select
    documentid, reference,
    (
        select max(documentid) from table as t2
        where t2.reference = t1.reference and t2.documentid < t1.documentid
    )
from table as t1;
```